# user profile links are not being fetched in user profile details API, previously some profile links were broken but now no response

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an app which manages leads, from FB APIs we used to get facebook user(leads) details, a few months back we faced with many users a problem of broken profile_links, but for others, these were working fine.

I raised a bug ticket for seeking the solution to this but they provided me with the links for this community and FB developer community for help regarding such issues.

Now I am facing an issue that no profile link is being retrieved with user details.

any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not just link to user profiles any more using the old formats (like by using the app-scoped user id), Facebook has removed this for privacy reasons.

You need to ask the user for [`user_link`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-user_link) permission first, and then you can request the `link` field of the user profile - it will return a URL containing a token, that redirects human visitors in their browser to the actual profile address. (That token is likely limited in validity and will expire at some point, so you should rather not store those URLs for long-term use, but request a fresh one when you need to link to a user profile.)